# CSS transition not working on dynamic set

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am having an issue dynamically using the CSS `transition` attribute for a simple JavaScript slide carousel.

The carousel works fine, but the CSS `transition` does not work as expected. Am I missing something here?

Here is a [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/xahilezeja/edit?html,css,js,output)

HTML

```
<div id="slider-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li data-active="true">Slide one</li>
      <li data-active="false">Slide two</li>
      <li data-active="false">Slide three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slider-wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    border: thin dotted;
    /* overflow-x: hidden; */
    height: 100px;
}

#slider-wrapper ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

#slider-wrapper ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 100%;
}

#slider-wrapper ul li[data-active='true'] {
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    transition: margin 1s;
}
```

JavaScript

```
// get slide deck (returns ul)
var slideDeck = document.getElementById('slider-wrapper').children[0];

/** slideIndex
  * @param integer
  * @return object
*/
function slideIndex(par) {
    for (var i = 0; i < slideDeck.children.length; i++) {
        if (slideDeck.children[i].getAttribute("data-active") == "true") {

            var activeSlide = slideDeck.children[i];
            var slideIndex;

            // previous slide
            if (par == -1) {
                // if currently on first slide
                if (i == 0) {
                    slideIndex = slideDeck.children.length - 1;
                }
                else {
                    slideIndex = i - 1;
                }
            }
            // current slide
            else if (par == 0) {
                slideIndex = i;
            }
            // next slide
            else if (par == 1) {
                // if currently on last slide
                if (i == slideDeck.children.length - 1) {
                    slideIndex = 0;
                }
                else {
                    slideIndex = i + 1;
                }
            }

            return {
                      el: slideDeck.children[slideIndex],
                      index: slideIndex
                   };
        }
    }
}

// run a timeout loop to linear transgression
setInterval(function() {
    // get slides
    var currentSlideElement = slideIndex(0).el;
    var previousSlideElement = slideIndex(-1).el;
    var nextSlideElement = slideIndex(1).el;

    currentSlideElement.setAttribute("data-active", "false");
    nextSlideElement.setAttribute("data-active", "true");

    console.log('ok');
}, 5500);
```

Comment: You have a different `display` value for each state. Even though you are trying to transition just the `margin`, the `display` change will affect it and nullify your `margin`. Try setting the default to block and you'll see your transition working (but of course your elements won't be where you expect them to be). Also, you should have a transition on the default element, not just the active state, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment:

> You have a different `display` value for each state. Even though you are trying to transition just the `margin`, the `display` change will affect it and nullify your `margin`.

You should try using `translate` and `opacity` instead, since you have fixed heights anyways (if this is supposed to be fluid based on content, this solution kind of falls apart, but that was not part of the question so I'm going to assume it's okay).

```js
// get slide deck (returns ul)
var slideDeck = document.getElementById('slider-wrapper').children[0];

/** slideIndex
  * @param integer
  * @return object
*/
function slideIndex(par) {
    for (var i = 0; i < slideDeck.children.length; i++) {
        if (slideDeck.children[i].getAttribute("data-active") == "true") {

            var activeSlide = slideDeck.children[i];
            var slideIndex;

            // previous slide
            if (par == -1) {
                // if currently on first slide
                if (i == 0) {
                    slideIndex = slideDeck.children.length - 1;
                }
                else {
                    slideIndex = i - 1;
                }
            }
            // current slide
            else if (par == 0) {
                slideIndex = i;
            }
            // next slide
            else if (par == 1) {
                // if currently on last slide
                if (i == slideDeck.children.length - 1) {
                    slideIndex = 0;
                }
                else {
                    slideIndex = i + 1;
                }
            }

            return {
                      el: slideDeck.children[slideIndex],
                      index: slideIndex
                   };
        }
    }
}

// run a timeout loop to linear transgression
setInterval(function() {
    // get slides
    var currentSlideElement = slideIndex(0).el;
    var previousSlideElement = slideIndex(-1).el;
    var nextSlideElement = slideIndex(1).el;

    currentSlideElement.setAttribute("data-active", "false");
    nextSlideElement.setAttribute("data-active", "true");

    console.log('ok');
}, 5500);
```

```css
#slider-wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    border: thin dotted;
    /* overflow-x: hidden; */
    height: 100px;
}

#slider-wrapper ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit; /* For consistency */
    position: relative; /* To contain each slide */
}

#slider-wrapper ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* Removed all float/margin related properties */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0; /* Hide it visually */
    pointer-events: none; /* Disable interactions */
    transform: translateX(100%); /* Move it away!*/
    transition: all 1s; /* Feel free to make this a concise list of properties */
}

#slider-wrapper ul li[data-active='true'] {
    opacity: 1; /* Show it */
    pointer-events: auto; /* Restore interactions */
    transform: translateX(0); /* Put it back in the centre */
}
```

```html
<div id="slider-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li data-active="true">Slide one</li>
      <li data-active="false">Slide two</li>
      <li data-active="false">Slide three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the transition in all `li`s instead of just the active one.

```css
#slider-wrapper ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 100%;
    transition: margin 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: The property "display: none;" is interfering with the animation. Since display is not an animatable property, you won't see the transition from "display: none;" to "display: block;"